# select onclick event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I need to test select box values using javascript. But Its outputs the previous value on click, don't know what would be the case.

Here's my code:

```
            $(document).ready(function(){ 

$('select').click(function(){ 
        var id = this.id;
    var text = $('#'+id+' :selected').text();
 alert(text);

     });
        });

<select id="combo">
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 4</option>
        <option value="5">Test 5</option>
        <option value="6">Test 6</option>
        <option value="7">Test 7</option>
    </select>
```

I gave the static id for testing purpose, but in real I want to take out the id from select box.

My question is, how can I get the exact value output(HTML) of options on click.

Comment: change event - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/26pLppph/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 


  alert($('#combo').val());
  alert($('#combo option:selected').text());
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="combo">
        <option value="1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="3">Test 3</option>
        <option value="4">Test 4</option>
        <option value="5">Test 5</option>
        <option value="6">Test 6</option>
        <option value="7">Test 7</option>
    </select>
```

You can use `$('select').val()`. This will give you the select field value. Listen for change event to capture the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the common and easy approach:

```
$("#combo").change(function(){
    var selectedvalue = $( "#combo option:selected" ).text();
});
```